# How can I get rid of Wasps in/above soffit?

Tags: pest-control, soffit

[image: Soffit View]

So we have some wasps/mud dobbers going into our eves where the soffit meets the siding. I purchased some long term spray which would hopefully get rid of the lady bugs that come in as well. Just want to see if anyone has other ideas. How would you get rid of the wasps? Thanks

Comment: We did something similar and the spray stained the siding. Eventually hired an exterminator because we also had an ant problem.

Comment: Did you know Wasps are useful animals. They eat other bugs and do not damage your home

Comment: @ Ruskes, I felt like you...live and let live....then 4 of them decided that I should not walk past the front of my garage and let me know in a very painful way.  I evicted them.

Comment: You could try spraying some orange oil.

Comment: @ Ruskes Sorry that's not helpful. Wife just texted that one got in the house somehow and this is right above the front door. My goal was mostly to see if I'm missing something. Like the soffit's installed wrong or if someone has another idea. Wasps can be helpful but not in this context.

Comment: @Nelson, please stop doing image enhancements.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest just using some clear caulk and filling those gaps so they can't get in.  Then hopefully they'll just find somewhere else to build their nests.  Won't get "rid" of them in the traditional sense, but will force them to look elsewhere.

Comment: There's nothing better than standing on a ladder being stung by wasps.